# PHP: xml_parser "Mismatched tag"-error when parsing HTML (auto-closing tags as <img>)?

Tags: php, html, parsing, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I want to parse HTML using PHPs. I used xml_parser for it, but it can't cope with auto-closing tags as `<img>`.

For example, the following HTML snippet produces a 'Mismatched tag' error when it reaches the closing tag `</a>`:

```
<a>
  <img src="URL"><br>
</a>
```

Obviosly, the reason is: xml_parser() doesn't know that the tags `<img>` and `<br>` do not need to be closed (as they are self-closing automatically).

I know that I could rewrite the HTML to `<img src="URL"/><br/>` to make the parser happy. However, I want the parser to correctly process those HTML correctly instead as the above variation would be valid HTML.

So I either need to tell the parser - within the onOpeningTag - if this tag is auto-closing. Is this possible somehow? An alternative could be to tell the parser a list of the self-closing tag names. However, I didn't find any function for that. So it might also be the case that 'HTML' isn't supported by this parser.

A acceptable solution might be to disable the tag mismatch check at all (or implement an HTML-compatible version myself).

However, there could be a HTML-specific version in PHP which I overlooked. Any suggestions which other simple parser implementations I could use?

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php

// Command Line Parsing...
$file = $argv[1];


// Tag Handler functions
function onOpeningTag($parser, $name, $attrs) {
  echo "OPEN: $name\n";
}

function onClosingTag($parser, $name) {
  echo "CLOSE: $name\n";
}

function onContent($parser, $text) {
  echo "TEXT (LEN:".strlen($text).")\n";
}

// Parser...
$xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, "onOpeningTag", "onClosingTag");
xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser, "onContent");

if (!($fp = fopen($file, "r"))) die("Could not open file '$file'.\n");
while ($data = fread($fp, 4096)) {
  if (!xml_parse($xml_parser, $data, feof($fp))) {
    die(sprintf("XML error: %s at line %d\n",
      xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($xml_parser)),
      xml_get_current_line_number($xml_parser)));
  }
}
fclose($fp);

xml_parser_free($xml_parser);


?>
```

Comment: run the html through html purifier to fix syntax errors like that. best to not try and fix it yourself with regexes or other string operations - mangled html tends to only get mangled worse.

Comment: As I said, this is -valid- HTML. I actually don't want to fix or change it as the output shall be HTML, too. Maybe I should mention that I want to write some kind of template engine, that actually copy&pastes most of the HTML into the output.

Comment: PS: I also need access to the comment blocks, which will contain the special template commands. Maybe I really need to write my own parser dedicated for this issue.

Comment: it's valid html, but it's not valid xml. run it through purifier to turn it into valid x-html, which should then also be valid xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to parse HTML with an XML parser and this is prone to cause headaches. XML is far stricter than HTML and you'll always run into problems like this. If your HTML is not huge - like tens of MBs, but rather a normal web page you can just use DOM - http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$lists = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ul');
// bla bla bla
```

My suggestion is to try a specialised library for HTML parsing. Here are some suggesions:

- https://github.com/symfony/DomCrawler
- http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/
- https://code.google.com/p/ganon/

May the force be with you!